# componentOne windows flexgrid automation using CodedUI C#

Tags: c#, automation, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I have only compiled exe application which i need to automate. It has c1.win.c1flexgrid of ComponentOne as Grid. I am using CodedUI to automate this application.

When using Coded UI Record & Playback, it do not highlight or find any row or column but only outer body of this flexgrid which is grid name. If i try to get its children, it return zero whereas, i can see there are lot of rows and columns in this FlexGrid.

I tried to get current patterns of this control using AutomationElement object and it returned me following two patterns as mentioned below.

It has only two patterns implemented.

1. LegacyIAccessiblePatternIdentifiers.Pattern
2. ScrollPatternIdentifiers.Pattern

I would like to know how i can automate this type of grid which do not have implemented any other automation pattern and is third party control.

I will be thankful to you if you can share sample or directions.

Regards,

Comment: Were you able to create tests for other controls? What do you mean by `this type of grid which do not have implemented any other automation pattern.`? No control implement these pattern these are the component of CodedUI automation library.

Comment: What happens when you use Coded UI's record and generate tool? What does the cross-hairs tool (the assertion builder) show as you drag the big-blue-rectangle around the screen and over the application? Please [edit] the question to show a lot more detail of what happens now and how that differs from what you want. It may be that the application, or the libraries it uses, do not support Coded UI. Please also note that asking for a tutorial is off-topic on this site.

Comment: In addition to the comment from @AdrainHHH: if you review the code generated from recording a test on that grid, does the test work with coordinates or with UITestControls for e.g. clicking on a grid cell. It you see coordinates being used, it means the test was unable to detect that control. You can search the internet for what steps to take solve that issue or ask a new question about it on this forum.

Comment: @PixelPlex I am asking same. It workes using coordinates but cannot find text withing this flexGrid. I am not asking for tutorial or solution but i am requesting if you can guide me how i can achieve it.

Comment: You  could always try and call `getChildren()` on the first detected parent control of that grid. Does it give you it's children? You can check by doing a debug session and using the watch in visual studio.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to describe what happens when you use the record and generate tool. Your comments may indicate that the program is using custom controls that Coded UI cannot "see" into. Controls need to be written to support Coded UI. You should check with the suppliers of `flexgrid` and `ComponentOne` and any other libraries (or whatever) that are being used. Ask them whether their product supports Coded UI and at what level of support.

Comment: @AdrianHHH consider it as a third party or custom control I have added details of record and playback using this control  .

Comment: You might find this post usful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606157/exposing-a-custom-control-to-coded-ui-tests-winforms

Its about adding accessibility to custom objects.

Comment: You have confirmed that it is a custom control, so you need to ask its suppliers as I said in my previous comment.